# Cauchy's integral formula in multiple connected domains

Tags: laurent-series, cauchy-integral-formula

I was looking at the derivation for the laurent series, but didn't catch why they could use Cauchy's integral formula in their proof...

I can see that the integral of a function around the boundaries of an annulus most be zero if the function is analytic in the domain of the annulus. And so $\oint_{c_1} f(z)dz+\oint_{c_2}f(z)dz=0$, if $c_1$ is the outer boundary counter-clockwise, and $c_2$ the inner boundary clockwise. The thing I don't understand is that these can be written as:

$\oint_{c_1} f(z)dz+\oint_{c_2}f(z)dz=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{c_1}\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}dz+\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{c_2}\frac{f(z)}{z-z_0}dz$,

Using the Cauchy's integral formula, which states that that the domain must be simply connected, which an annulus isn't, if I'm not mistaken. What am I missing?

Comment: The equation you wrote is wrong, the left hand side is $0$, and the right is $f(z_0)$ (assuming $f$ is holomorphic on the annulus). Cauchy's integral formula doesn't require the domain to be simply connected. What it requires is that the cycle one integrates over doesn't wind around any point outside the domain. And that's pretty clear for the boundary of any sufficiently nice open set.

Comment: Yeah.. This is entirely false, sorry! I don't know what I was thinking. I've been looking at this for half an hour so that's just a big brainfart. The actual equation was $f(z) = g(z) + h(z) = $right side of the above equation. My problem was with $g$ and $h$ being used Cauchy's on. Cauchy's is stated on a simply connected domain in my textbook though, but perhaps I've missed a generalization or something then.

Comment: Yes, some textbooks only state the integral (theorem and) formula only for simply connected domains. I never understood why. Sure, it saves the two lines necessary to say what a nullhomologous cycle is, but it loses much more convenience later.